# Custom Google Assistant suddenly not available on device, but works when the prompt is typed in

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have been building this DialogFlow and had been testing it on my tablet device. I had previously set the Language to English (United States) to access it. After opening Google Assistant, I said the "Talk to " phrase and it would pull up my Custom Google Assistant. I'm able to test and debug using my Android Tablet.

However, when I tried to test just now, it told me that my Custom Google Assistant "isn't available on devices set up for your language or country." I haven't changed anything is the setup of the tablet nor my DialogFlow or the Google Actions.

What's odd is if I type in the "Talk to ", I'm able to use my assistant and talk to it.

I'm not sure what's wrong with my device or my Custom Google Assistant. Testing it over at the Actions on Google and calling my Custom Google Assistant via the voice prompt works.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... Thought I was going mad but we have been trying to fix this problem for hours yesterday. We have no other conclusion that the problem lies with Google. I'm happy I found your post to confirm we're not the only people having this problem... We didn't change anything and suddenly this problem occured since yesterday

Comment: Hi. Same problem here. We are using German Google Accounts and are unable to invoke our English and French development AoGs. Happening since yesterday.

Comment: Same here, I'm unable to access our actions on my Google Home or through voice on the Google Assistant app. Strange thing is, it works on the simulator and when I enter "talk to [My app]" through text on the assistant app, then it does go through..

Comment: The issue has been resolved for me, I can reach all my actions again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I send in a ticket to the Actions on Google support yesterday.
Today they replied with an email that it is a known issue and other people are facing the same problem like us. Their internal team is working on it and they expect a fix within the next 24 - 48 hours.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same bug since yesterday - very annoying! I'm trying to invoke my development US action from Germany (location targeting is enabled for all available countries in the Action on Google Console) and was receiving the message "XXXX isn't available on devices set up for your country. Sorry about that.".

I was able to bypass it while Google is hopefully fixing it on their side: I installed a GPS faker ("Fake GPS") on my Android device and changed my location to San Francisco.... now I can invoke my AoG without any problems.